# Can't do chown/chgrp/chmod on shared dir in VirtualBox Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I installed [Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) on my Ubuntu 10.04 VM running out of `VirtualBox` in order to enable directory sharing, following [these instructions](http://mylinuxramblings.wordpress.com/2010/06/03/installing-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-ubuntu-server-10-04/).  Set the shared folder in the VirtualBox GUI and it mounted it on the VM, where it appeared fine.

However, when I tried going into the shared directory on the VM (located in `/media`), I could not `cd` into it nor change ownership or permissions, the commands returning without an error but not actually having done their job:

```
mysuser@ubnt-xdev:/media$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 2013-08-28 11:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root   4096 2013-08-28 10:48 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 2013-08-28 11:29 cdrom
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf   68 2013-08-28 11:19 sf_vmshare
mysuser@ubnt-xdev:/media$ cd sf_v*
-bash: cd: sf_vmshare: Permission denied
mysuser@ubnt-xdev:/media$ sudo chown mysuser sf_vmshare
[sudo] password for mysuser: 
mysuser@ubnt-xdev:/media$ ls -la sf_vmshare
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf   68 2013-08-28 11:19 sf_vmshare
mysuser@ubnt-xdev:/media$ sudo chgrp mysuser sf_vmshare
mysuser@ubnt-xdev:/media$ ls -la sf_vmshare
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf   68 2013-08-28 11:19 sf_vmshare
mysuser@ubnt-xdev:/media$ sudo chmod 777 sf_vmshare
mysuser@ubnt-xdev:/media$ ls -la sf_vmshare
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf   68 2013-08-28 11:19 sf_vmshare
```

Which makes the shared directory unusable.  The directory works fine on the host.  Anybody know what is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, the user needs to be added to the `vboxsf` group:

```
sudo adduser mysuser vboxsf
```

Then restart the VM.

Comment: I think that you meant restart session or opening another login.

Comment: Doesn't help for me.

Comment: doesn't help for me either. chmod not taking affect.